# Index out of array? MP3

Tags: c#, mp3

I have this MP3 player which looks like this:

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=mkvzly&s=8#.U3My1_l_uEo

I can use the buttons without problem, they're working fine. The problem is coming when I want to play the songs. If i add 1 song to the listbox, doubleclick it, it is playing! Awesome? Well yea, except the fact if I add another song, the first song is still clickable and is playing, but as soon as I click on any other song than the first, it crashes.

I am getting following error:

> Listbox index out of array

Heres the code which contain the error:

```
string[] files, paths;

private void lbplaylist_DoubleMouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start på event
{
    player.URL = paths[lbplaylist.SelectedIndex];
}
```

Help please.
Complete code with suggestion implented:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WORKS_EKSAMENSPROJEKT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string[] files, paths;

        private void lbplaylist_DoubleMouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start på event
        {
            if (lbplaylist.SelectedItem != null)
                player.URL = (lbplaylist.SelectedItem as Song).Path;
        }
        private void btOpenFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Filter = ("MP3 Files| *.mp3|Wave Files| *.wav|WMA Files|*.wma|All Files|*.*");
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
                paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames; 
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    lbplaylist.Items.Add(files[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        private void btReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbplaylist.Items.Clear();
        }
        public class Song
        {
            public string Title;
            public string Path;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Title;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return ToString().GetHashCode();
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is Song)
                    return this.Path.Equals(((Song)obj).Path);
                else
                    return base.Equals(obj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To start debugging, you have to know what did `paths` contain and the value of `lbplaylist.SelectedIndex`.

Comment: It sounds like even though you update your listbox, you don't replicate this change to whatever paths is. You also could add error handling to this so your end user doesn't get an error (`if(paths.Length >= SelectedIndex)`)

Comment: What do you mean, *should* contain the error? Are you sure that this portion of code throws the error or not?

Comment: Rechecked and this IS the error line

Comment: user, whether or not this is the line that throws the error is irrelevant. The problem is down to wherever you determine the size of paths in relation to the listbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most obvious cause of the error is that `paths` doesn't have the second entry. The question is why. If you add another song to the play list, you need to make sure that a new entry is also added to `paths`.

It might be a good idea to do the following:

1. Create a new helper class called `Song` which contains the title and the path to the MP3 file. Override its `ToString()` method to return the song title.
2. When adding a new song to the playlist, create a new instance of `Song` with the appropriate information and add that to the listbox.
3. When an entry is double-clicked, play the file from the path of the selected `Song` object, not another list in your code.

That way you only have to maintain one list.

Example:

```
public class Song
{
    public string Title;
    public string Path;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Song)
            return this.Path.Equals(((Song)obj).Path);
        else
            return base.Equals(obj);
    }
}
```

Then the code for double-clicking a list item comes down to:

```
private void lbplaylist_DoubleMouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e) // Start på event
{
    if (lbplayList.SelectedItem != null)
        player.URL = (lbplayList.SelectedItem as Song).Path;
}
```

To add a new file to the playlist you can use this:

```
Song s = new Song() { Title = title, Path = filePath };
lbplayList.Items.Add(s);
```

Please note that `filePath` should contain the full path to an MP3 file (path + name).

---

To add the `Song` items to the playlist properly, please use this:

```
private void btOpenFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = ("MP3 Files|*.mp3|Wave Files|*.wav|WMA Files|*.wma|All Files|*.*");

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
        {
            Song s = new Song() { Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), Path = file };
            lbplaylist.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it is now pretty obvious why you got the error in the first place! With every click to `btnOpenFiles` you set `paths` to contain *only* the last selected files names. So if you selected one file upon the first click and another on the second click, the list box would contain two entries, but `paths` would contain only the last selection.

Comment: Would an alternatie way of fixin this just creating more player.URL = paths[lbplaylist.SelectedIndex]; lines?

Comment: No. I've written an alternative way as an edit. The problem is that `paths` contains less entries than your listbox. Whenever you add a new entry to the listbox, you also need to add a new entry to `paths`. Or you go with my approach, which is much cleaner.

Comment: Wouldn't your method make it necesarry the music files should be same place? Then my "open files" feature would be useless?

Comment: No, as ever `Song` instance can take an individual path to any file in the file system. See my edit with code.

Comment: Tried your method, gets another error: Object reference not setto an instance of an object

Comment: What line of my code? Are you sure that you're adding `Song` instances and not strings? Please edit your question and show the code you use to add items to `lbplayList`. This method works - I've tried it many times, though not for media players, but that's the way to go.

Comment: player.URL = (lbplaylist.SelectedItem as Song).Path; this line

Comment: Well, then either `lbplaylist.SelectedItem` is `null` (which can not be, as I'm checking this in my code) or `lbplayList.SelectedItem` is not an instance of the `Song` class. In that case you didn't do as I said :-)

Comment: I posted what I did. I am trying to follow, but I am no genious in this subject :P

Comment: In the code you posted above you're **not** adding an instance of `Song`, but a string: `lbplaylist.Items.Add(files[i]);` You need to add an instance of  `Song`!

Comment: Would it be somethinglike lbplaylit.song? >.<

Comment: No, I already wrote this in my answer, but I'm going to edit again with your code to make it clear...

Comment: Thank you, great help. It have confused me so much

Comment: I am getting an error on the Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension (the Path is error), tells it is not in this context. Suppose I need "Song s = new Song() { Title = title, Path = filePath };
lbplayList.Items.Add(s);" but where to put it?

Comment: To use the `Path` class, add `using System.IO;` at the top of the file among all the other using statements. I start to wonder whether your `EKSAMENSPROJEKT` is actually your first project in C# at all... ;-)

Comment: You are my savior! It worked. It is indeed one of my first own project when I am all by myself!